# IndexOutOfBoundsException in DataProvider query using Java 8 Stream

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream, vaadin, vaadin14

I want to lazy load filtered data from the backend. If I apply a filter that returns 1 element (or no filter applied) from the backend everything works fine.

It starts to crash / throw a `OutOfBoundsException` if the fetched items are more than 1. I used the [official Vaadin documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/datamodel/datamodel-providers.html#lazy-filtering) as a guideline for my implementation.

The exception is thrown in the .`filter()` method of the Stream-API. I am also aware of the meaning of the exception, the index that tries to access the values are >= the max size of the List but I am not sure how to fix this. Setting the limit to limit-1 of the first query didn't fix it.

I think I am doing something wrong with the second query in the callback but I can't figure out what the issue is. Is it an Stream-API issue or does the second callback query not work correctly?

```
public DataProvider<T, String> createLazyLoadingProvider(List<T> data) {
        DataProvider<T, String> lazyLoadingProvider
                = DataProvider.fromFilteringCallbacks(query -> {
                    // First Query
                    final int offset = query.getOffset();
                    final int limit = query.getLimit();
                    final String filter = query.getFilter().orElse("");

                    return data
                            .stream()
                            .skip(offset)
                            .limit(limit)
                            .filter(e -> {
                                return e.toString().startsWith(filter);
                            });


                }, query -> {
                    // Second query
                    return (int) data.stream()
                            .filter(e -> {
                                return e.toString().startsWith(filter);
                            })
                            .count();
                });
        return lazyLoadingProvider;
    }
```

Produces:

```
First Query
Offset: 0
Limit: 100
Callback-Filter: 3
Full Size of Data: 6005
From backend fetched Items: 5
-----------
Second Query
Offset: 0
Limit: 2147483647
Callback-Filter: 3
Max fetchable Items with filter applied: 381
```

Stacktrace:

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 5 out of bounds for length
>   5     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
>     at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)     at
>   java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:458)     at
>   com.vaadin.flow.data.provider.DataCommunicator.lambda$getJsonItems$3(DataCommunicator.java:611)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.IntPipeline$1$1.accept(IntPipeline.java:180)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$RangeIntSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:104)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.Spliterator$OfInt.forEachRemaining(Spliterator.java:699)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.flow.data.provider.DataCommunicator.getJsonItems(DataCommunicator.java:613)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.flow.data.provider.DataCommunicator.collectChangesToSend(DataCommunicator.java:556)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.flow.data.provider.DataCommunicator.flush(DataCommunicator.java:473)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.flow.data.provider.DataCommunicator.lambda$requestFlush$2f364bb9$1(DataCommunicator.java:421)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.flow.internal.StateTree.lambda$runExecutionsBeforeClientResponse$1(StateTree.java:364)
>     at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)   at
>   com.vaadin.flow.internal.StateTree.runExecutionsBeforeClientResponse(StateTree.java:361)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlWriter.encodeChanges(UidlWriter.java:392)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlWriter.createUidl(UidlWriter.java:182)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.writeUidl(UidlRequestHandler.java:116)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:89)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.flow.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1540)
>     at
>   com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:246)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:760)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1617)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:226)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:545)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:536)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1592)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1296)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:485)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1562)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1211)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:221)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:717)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:500)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:386)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:562)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:378)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:270)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onFillable(SslConnection.java:543)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:398)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$2.succeeded(SslConnection.java:161)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:388)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: Could you provide the full stack trace?

Comment: @poisn I don't think your link will help me. As I wrote in the question I am aware of the meaning of the exception. The DataProvider is used in the scope of vaadin and I don't think the answer is such easy.

Comment: @SándorJuhos Complete stacktrace was added.

Comment: This link might help for you:
https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/6072

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to filter *before* you apply the offset and limit.

**Elaboration:**

Say you have the items `Apple, Cucumber, Lemon, Lettuce, Linseed, Lime, Tangerine, Tomato` and want the filter to only include ones starting with `L`.

Your count query returns a count of 4 (`Lemon, Lettuce, Linseed, Lime`).

Now say the grid needs the first two items, so it sends offset 0 and limit 2.

What your code does is selects the first two items, `Apple, Cucumber`, then filters them, and returns 0 items.

What it needs to do is filter the items to get `Lemon, Lettuce, Linseed, Lime`, then take offset 0 and limit 2 to get `Lemon, Lettuce`.